# Properly orienting a 3D mesh to point in the direction it's heading

Tags: opengl, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to get a mesh to traverse a circuit across a sphere. I took the image that is wrapped around the sphere, and coloured the path that I want the mesh to follow. Then I computed all of the (u, v) points of the path. Using the (u, v) points, I convert to spherical coordinates to get the mesh onto the sphere, and set the rotations around the X and Y axes `rot.x` and `rot.y`, so that the mesh is tangent to the sphere and faces the north pole of the sphere. My problem is getting the mesh to face the direction it's heading in. The third rotation variable, `rot.z`, is used to set the heading of the mesh. Currently, I get the (u, v) points from the 5th to 14th points to come, and take the average of the angles of elevation of the line segment of the current point and each of the 10 future points. This works, but the two drawbacks are that the heading vibrates very frequently, and also the heading has a tendency to be inaccurate when turning somewhat sharply. What is a good method for calculating the heading of the mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach is to build a rotation matrix. With that you don't have to think about angles, because if you know the direction and either the up or right vector all entries can be calculated. In your case the direction is the tangent on the sphere and the up vector the normal at that point.

```
vec3 direction = tangent;
vec3 up = normal;
vec3 right = cross(direction,up);

mat3 m;
m[0] = right;
m[1] = up;
m[2] = direction;
```

Comment: That's the problem: calculating the direction vector in your method, or setting a rotation angle in mine. Since I'm dealing with a sphere, I'd be looking at a tangent plane, not a line. The mesh is oriented so that I use ``rot.x`` and ``rot.y`` to ensure that the mesh is on the tangent plane (so I could calculate the ``up`` vector), but I'm trying to get the appropriate direction based on the points that the mesh is going to.

Comment: What is the problem then? There are infinite possible vectors in the tangent plane. It shouldn't be so hard to find one ;).

Comment: Basically, I've got a list of about 5000 (u, v) points that make up the path that gets travelled. Given index ``i`` of the path, I look at points ``i+5`` to ``i+14`` and sum ``arctan2(v2-v1, u2-u1)``. It works, but it results in the angle of the mesh jumping around a lot, and I'm trying to find a method to make the angle change more smoothly

Comment: So you want to travel from `p1` to `p2` on the sphere? A direction vector can easily be computed with  2 cross-products. `d = p2-p1; up=normalize(p1-middle); right = cross(d,up); direction=cross(up,right);`

Comment: And I assume ``middle`` is the centre of the sphere?

Comment: Given, the direction vector, how can I get the rotations around the axes -- I'm using an environment that uses rotation angles, not direction vectors? For reference, the centre of rotations and the sphere is the origin.

Comment: Just rotate the point (with angles or whatever) and calculate the direction in every frame. That should although give you a 'smooth' rotation.

Comment: But the mesh is rotated by changing the rotation variables, not with a direction vector. I'm missing how to take the direction vector for points ``p1`` and ``p2`` and get the rotation around an axis.